# How do I check for an empty nested list in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

Say I have a list like

```
cata = [["Shelf", 12, "furniture", [1,1]],
        ["Carpet", 50, "furnishing", []]]
```

and I want to find out in each nested list if it's empty or not.

I am aware of using for loops to iterate through the lists, and if statements to verify as I have in a function

```
def myfunc(cata):
    for inner in cata:
        for inner_2 in inner[3]:
            if inner_2:
                return "True"
            else:
                return "False"
```

However instead of returning:

```
'True'
'False'
```

All I get is:

```
'False'
```

Is there some method of searching nested loops that I'm missing?

Comment: Could be rewritten as `return [str(bool(inner[3])) for inner in cata]`

Comment: You are returning the strings `'True'` and `'False'` instead of the boolean values `True` and `False`. Are you certain this is what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're `return`ing from the function, that essentially means that you don't evaluate every element.

Apart from that `for inner_2 in inner[3]:` will not do what you want because it won't execute for empty lists (*it doesn't have elements to iterate though!*). What you could do is go through each list and `yield` the thuth-ness of `inner[3]`:

```
def myfunc(cata):
    for inner in cata:
        yield bool(inner[3])
```

`yield`ing will make the function a generator that can be iterated over and return your results:

```
for i in myfunc(cata):
    print(i)
```

Prints:

```
True
False
```

Of course, this can easily be transformed to a list comprehension that stores the results:

```
r = [bool(x[3]) for x in cata]
```

With `r` now holding:

```
[True, False]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Also if I wanted to instead add up the numbers in a list, could I essentially use `r = [int(x[3]) for x in cata`  ?

Comment: @SabafapBing, you could use `sum(x[3])` to sum the numbers, `int()` can't take a list as argument.